# auto login to a wrbsite and extract elements

Tags: javascript, html, moodle

I want a make an **html** page that can auto login to a *site* and then navigate to another page of that *site* and get some elements and display them on my **html** page using java script the site is based on MOODLE-API is there any way to do this.

I've tried using this curl an php script but it didnt helped since moodle api uses cookies to login that go away as soon as the user closes the browser.
the website is https://edumate.raoiit.com/login/index.php

```
<?php

    //Upload a blank cookie.txt to the same directory as this file with a CHMOD/Permission to 777
function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  

function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}

function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
        $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);    
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make an attempt and post what you have tried so that we can help you.

Comment: Well, take a look into XMLHttpRequest (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp), and then use them. But I think using something like PHP would make it a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code cannot work, since `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` both require an **absolute** path to the file. the easiest way is to use `realpath('cookie.txt')`.

And if the website really has cookies which are removed on exit, just create a global `$ch = curl_init();` object, and use it in the methods by writing `global $ch;` at the very beginning of a method, an *not* calling `curl_init()` or `curl_close()` in any method.